# Is it possible to build WinDBG extensions using Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windbg

To build **WinDBG** debugger **extensions**, must we use the *Build* utility that comes with the WDK, or can we use Visual Studio?
(In particular, I'd be interested in VS2010 SP1.)

According to the documentation of *Debugging Tools for Windows*, the only option should be the Build utility:

*Windows Debugging | Debugger Engine and Extension API | Introduction*

> All debugger extensions should be compiled and built by using the
>   Build utility. The Build utility is included in the Windows Driver Kit
>   (WDK).

...but maybe the doc is not updated?

Moreover, *why* would the Build utility the only option for building WinDBG extensions?
What "gotchas" are hidden there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing particularly special in the case of WinDBG extensions - just build a DLL, with the right set of function names and calling convention, and off you go. So Visual Studion should be able to do that perfectly fine.

You do need to produce your own .def file for the DLL to export the functions.

This page describes how you do it using `nmake`. The same steps should be perfectly possible to do in VS.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6522/Debug-Tutorial-Part-4-Writing-WINDBG-Extensions

Comment: Thanks... So I'm assuming there is a "documentation bug" in the aforementioned paragraph.

Comment: Maybe. I'd see it more as a "this is how we do it in MS, and we suggest you do it that way too". Although it uses the word "should", I think it doesn't actually say "You must do this", it just say "you can do it this way". Of course, one advantage with "build" is that it uses the version of the compiler that the WDK uses, which is (likely) also the compiler used for the WinDBG that comes with that WDK, so there won't be any minor compiler bug issues that cause problems - this could be why they suggest that you do that. Of course, the MS author may have a different meaning in mind my thinking.